# adding records to xsd file using linq and C#

Tags: c#, linq, xsd

I use an xsd file for enumerations. For some reasons, i need to add a few thousands new enumarations to my xsd file. It has the follwoing format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xsd:simpleType name="tProduct">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="*HS-*HS" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="ADALV" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="AEAAN" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="AEAUH" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="AEDHF" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="AEDWC" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="AEDXB" />
......
....

I need to add the followings:

  <xsd:enumeration value="AEDXB11" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="AEDXB12" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="AEDXB13" />
....
```

How can i do this using linq and C#? Note that i will get the new values from a database and they will be stored in a list of strings.

My problem is i'm not sure i can open and manipulate this file as a pure xml file.

many thanks in advance

Yordi

Comment: Do you mean adding new lines to a particular location in the file or just add a line at the end of the file?

Comment: yes, just anywhere. It does not really matter. As long as the new lines are inserted.

Comment: anywhere after : <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="*HS-*HS" />

Comment: I know how to add lines to a text file, would you like me to post it or it won't help?

Comment: I guess that would do ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to add lines at the end of a text file:

```
//Set the contect of the new line
string content = @"<xsd:enumeration value="AEDXB11" />"; 

string FilePath = System.IO.Path(@"path\to\file.txt");  

//Add the text as a new line  
File.AppendAllText(FilePath , Environment.NewLine + content);
```

Hope this helps.